# EF Model Generation issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have added a class and created a migration, but when I come to update the db I get an error.  Its confusing me because I do have a key! Any ideas?

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> ModuleStatus: : EntityType 'ModuleStatus' has no
>   key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. ModuleStatus:
>   EntityType: EntitySet 'ModuleStatus' is based on type 'ModuleStatus'
>   that has no keys defined.

The class

```
public class ModuleStatus
{
    [Key]
    public int ModuleStatusId { get; set; }

    public Guid ModuleId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string NetworkAddress { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ModuleDescription { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ModuleVersion { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan UpTime { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

The migration looks like this

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.ModuleStatus",
            c => new
                {
                    ModuleStatusId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    ModuleId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    NetworkAddress = c.String(maxLength: 100),
                    ModuleName = c.String(maxLength: 100),
                    ModuleDescription = c.String(maxLength: 100),
                    ModuleVersion = c.String(maxLength: 50),
                    UpTime = c.Time(nullable: false, precision: 7),
                    LastUpdated = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ModuleStatusId);

    }
```

Stack trace:

> ModuleStatus: : EntityType 'ModuleStatus' has no key defined. Define
>   the key for this EntityType. ModuleStatus: EntityType: EntitySet
>   'ModuleStatus' is based on type 'ModuleStatus' that has no keys
>   defined.
>
> at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel.Validate()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ForceOSpaceLoadingForKnownEntityTypes()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()
>   at ---.---DataContext..ctor() in e:\App
>   Dev\Gazelle -
>   EstateManager\CI-MAIN\---\---\---Context.cs:line
>   28
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo.CreateInstance()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type
>   contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config,
>   DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func`1 resolver)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState
>   existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run() 
>   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate
>   callBackDelegate)    at
>   System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String
>   targetMigration, Boolean force)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command)

**Update 2**
Turns out it only fails when I have this line within my `DataContext`

```
    public IDbSet<Site> Sites { get; set; } // works fine with this in
    //public IDbSet<ModuleStatus> ModuleStatuses { get; set; } // fails if this is commented in
```

Comment: Any chance you are using `System.Data.Entity.dll` instead of `EntityFramework.dll`?

Comment: Using `EntityFramework.dll` as far as I know :)

Comment: You don't really need to add the `[Key]` attribute if the property name is `Id` or `[ClassName]Id`, though I would be really surprised if that 'extra' attribute would be the cause... What does your migration look like?

Comment: Updated the question with my migration... Our DB has many entities in and I've never seen this problem before.  You are right though it looks correct, I cant think what could be causing this

Comment: Maybe one of the atypical fields is causing this. If you remove the GUID and the Timespan fields, do the migration works?

Comment: Nothing stands out. Could you include the stack trace as well?

Comment: @RafaelMerlin Good idea, Ive tried that though and still no joy unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

May be worth a shot to put this in your DbContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ModuleStatus>().HasKey(x = x.ModuleStatusId);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Not sure if this will help, but worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Chris, please refer to the following link: [Entity FrameWork Database Migrations](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp.net-mvc-4-and-entity-framework-database-migrations)

There may be a conflict or ambiguity taking place. The [Key] annotation is somewhat redundant since the overridden Up() method already defines the primary key.  Try removing the [Key] annotation and let us know if this solves the issue.